# Auto fill blank cells with cell value, if condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

Initial layout

[image]

I am attempting to auto fill column C with type column B title, from the nth instance where column A = "D", and to automatically populate the value, until the next occurrence of A = "D", then use the next instance where column A = "D".

Desired output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XLOOKUP that searches from the bottom up and use dynamic ranges:

```
=XLOOKUP("D",$A$1:A2,$B$1:B2,"",0,-1)
```

[image]

Or if you want it to spill:

```
=SCAN("",ROW(A2:A13),LAMBDA(z,y,XLOOKUP("D",$A$1:INDEX(A:A,y),$B$1:INDEX(B:B,y),"",0,-1)))
```

[image]

---

Then there is the simply dragdown formula:

```
=IF(A2="D",B2,C1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know am late here, but here is my attempt using `XLOOKUP()` & `SCAN()`:

[image]

---

```
=LET(a, "D"&SCAN(0,A2:A18="D",LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,x))), XLOOKUP(a,a,B2:B18))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to not use XLOOKUP in this case:

`=SCAN("",A2:A18,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="D",OFFSET(b,,1),a)))`

Or to avoid OFFSET:
`=LET(a,A2:A18,b,B2:B18,SCAN("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(INDEX(a,y)="D",INDEX(b,y),x))))`

Or using XLOOKUP and MAP to spill:
`=MAP(A2:A18,B2:B18,LAMBDA(a,b,XLOOKUP("D",A2:a,B2:b,,,-1)))`